# No non-manifold geometry but Boolean needed for 3d printing still not working

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing

I have been making a figure to be 3d printed. I need to combine it with booleans for the printing software.
I have combined all of the model into 2 parts but for some reason I get the error message below on the last modifier. There is no non-manifold geometry in either object. The model has loads of vertices so my computer runs too slow in edit mode to manually edit the boundary and since I can't see it I'd have no idea where to start. I have attached images of the model with both objects and with only one. Thankyou :)[image: Error Message]

[image: Both objects][image: Single object]

Comment: which Blender version? Try 2.79b and both *bmesh* and *carve* solvers. Make really sure your meshes are manifold, how did you checked without edit mode?

Comment: I didn't realise I was using 2.72b - I will update and try that as my version doesn't have those options.  I can use edit mode but it's too complex to make many changes at a reasonable speed. Thankyou